# C3 graph overflow from Bootstrap 4 accordion card

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, c3.js

I am trying to insert a c3 graph into a Bootstrap accordion component. On the active card graph looks good, but if you expand the **Card 2** right edge of the graph goes over the card edge.

[image]

Is there an update event I need to pass to c3 to re-render on the expansion of the card?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5ysqLkj/2/)

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                Card 2
            </a>
        </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body pl-0">
            <div id="chart2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to flush the chart on showing the collapse element

```
      $('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
          chart1.flush();
          chart2.flush();
      })
```

Downside of this approach is that update is not so smooth, you can see the chart size jumping on collapse.